# Jenkins queue priority with several builds of the same job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, priority-queue

We have a pipeline that runs a job concurrently several times with different parameters.
Is there any way of making sure that the those jobs get into the queue **in a certain order**?

---

We want to make sure that the job launched in the first stage (`job A with X parameters`) gets *always enqueued before* the rest of the jobs enqueued by later stages.

```
parallel(
  { // job A with X parameters },
  { // job A with Y parameters },
  { // job A with Z parameters },
)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Question - do you need job A to finish before the others?  I believe they will be started in the order you specify, but depending on how they are allocated to your agents, there is no guarantee on the order in their steps are performed or in which order they will finish.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Priority Sorter Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Priority+Sorter+Plugin) the plugin can help you maybe.